# List expressions in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I'm parsing a `xml` file ... so there's a field called `case`: Sometimes it's a single `OrderedDict`, other times it's a list of `OrderedDict`. That's it:

```
OrderedDict([(u'duration', u'2.111'), (u'className', u'foo'), (u'testName', u'runTest'), (u'skipped', u'false'), (u'failedSince', u'0')])


[OrderedDict([(u'duration', u'0.062'), (u'className', u'foo'), (u'testName', u'runTest'), (u'skipped', u'false'), (u'failedSince', u'0')]), OrderedDict([(u'duration', u'0.461'), (u'className', u'bar'), (u'testName', u'runTest'), (u'skipped', u'false'), (u'failedSince', u'0')])]
```

I want to always have that expression as a single list. The reason is to have a `for` loop to take care of that. I thought about doing something like:

```
[case]
```

But as the later I would have `[[case]]`.  I don't think list joins or concatenations would help me. A trivial solution would be to check if `case` is of the type `list` or `OrderedDict`, however I was looking for a simpler, one line, pythonic solution like the one  I described above. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I would simply check the type if I were you.

Comment: @Ajay no I need everything ... I tried using `sets`

Answer (score 3):

Since `list` and `OrderedDict` are both kinds of containers, checking the type sounds like it might be the simplest solution, if you're sure that the xml parse will always use the `list` type.

There's no reason you can't do this in a one-liner:

```
case = [case] if not isinstance(case, list) else case
```